# Tableau Creating a set of phone numbers with a condition

Tags: list, conditional-statements, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to create a set, or a list containing phone numbers only if column1 = True. I'm not sure if this is how tableau works, I'm thinking the python way where you append phone numbers to the list given the condition.

this is a call records, my dataset looks like this

phoneNumber condition
1111111111  True
2222222222  null
3333333333  null
1111111111  null
4444444444  True
4444444444  null
5555555555  null
6666666666  True

I'm trying to create a set, or a list of phone numbers with 'condition' = true. In this case, [1111111111,4444444444, 6666666666]. I'm having duplicated phoneNumber because same person could call in multiple times, and the condition won't be true every single time. I will count them in if the condition is true for at least once

Ultimately, I'm trying to create a calculated field to match the phone number to this list.
If phoneNumber IN List THEN XXX END

Answer (score 0):

Tableau treats the boolean value True as greater than False
So `MIN(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE ...) = FALSE`
and `MAX(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE ...) = TRUE`

This means **MIN**() can be read as "**EVERY** row satisfies condition",
while **MAX**() can be interpreted as "**SOME** row satisfies condition"

You can define a set based on a condition

So a set based on the phoneNumber field using the condition either MIN(condition) or MAX(condition) depending on whether you want the EVERY call satisfies condition, or SOME call satisfies condition semantics.

It will be a set of phone numbers, that you can use on visualizations, filters or calculations. To reference a set from a calculation, just reference the set by name (you don't set `IF phoneNumber IN List`, say `IF myPhoneNumberSet`. It acts like a boolean function -- true if the associated phone number is a member of the set

Last point, *aggregation functions like MIN() and MAX() ignore null values* - as if they are completely invisible. Depending on what you're doing you might be better changing null to a default value, say False, to avoid confusing logic. An easy way to do that is with the function IFNULL() - its like coalesce in SQL.

A good way is to rename your original field to, say, condition-original. Define a new calculated field called original to supply the default value if needed, such as `IFNULL(condition, FALSE)`. Then use this revised condition in your calcs.